# Parsing XML from String Imported from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, xml

I have imported a query from SQL Server where the item is a stored XML script. It's being saved as a pyodbc item and I need to parse it as XML.

```
import pyodbc
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


# Create connection
con = pyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",server="Server",database="Database")
cur = con.cursor()
db_cmd = "SELECT [XML] FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table] where ID = 1"
res = cur.execute(db_cmd)

for row in res.fetchall():
    print(row)

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(str(row)))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:...", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-46-1e4a5c1ba170>", line 15, in <module>
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(str(row)))

  File "C:...", line 1315, in XML
    parser.feed(text)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

I'm guessing there is an issue with the XML script but I don't know enough about XML to determine what the issue is. Here is an excerpt of the script:

```
('<response error_code="0"><xml_root><report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
   <report_options>...;/html&gt;</html_root></response>', )
```

I tried saving it as a string as you can see from my code but I get the above error. How can I read in the value from SQL and save it as an XML item? The XML is redacted for privacy reasons but if more details are required, please let me know.

Comment: What is the data type of the XML column in SQL Server?

Comment: Please update your question and share the obfuscated XML in its entirety.

Comment: Can't do that, it's Financial Information, but I have confirmed that it is correctly formatted, but correct me if I'm wrong, I think think the issue is the parenthesis before and after the two response lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are accidently passing a row object, rather than string to `ET.fromstring(str(row))`

Try:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(str(row[0])))
```

According to the [pyodbc docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Row), you may also be able to reference the column by name, e.g. `row['XML']`, rather than `row[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well- formed:

**XML**

```
<response error_code="0"><xml_root><report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
   <report_options>...;/html&gt;</html_root></response>
```

**Error**

```
Parsing error: expected end of tag 'report_options' (line 3, column 20)
```

Comment: The OP does say 'The XML is redacted for privacy reasons'.

Comment: I thought that the OP obfuscated just the text values, and no the XML tags.

Comment: I don't think that that would have given them an error at line 1 column 0.  It looks to me as if the OP is getting a tuple back from the database, converting that to a string using `str` and attempting to parse the result of that.